# Remove my name from a distribution group in outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange-2010

Our corporate distribution groups were created with the option to allow members to remove themselves from the list.  I can find no option or method for an email recipient to do this.  Is it possible?

Comment: You may be able to find the Distribution Group in your global address list. Right-click on the name and go to Properties. Is there anything in that window that pertains to membership?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about corporate IT.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. On the Home tab of the ribbon in Outlook, click Address Book (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>)
2. Double click on the distribution group that is in question
3. Click Modify Members
4. Select your user name in the list and click Remove
5. Click OK and OK again.

Answer (score 1):

I think Owners of Distribution list (DL) can manage it using Outlook Address Book.
If DL is is open to join/leave user can add/remove themself only using OWA (in Options -> General -> Distribution groups). Outlook will not allow it due to 'insufficient permissions'.
Tested on Exchange 2016 + Outlook 365 1909.

Comment: This is dependent on config, and OP already notes their org has granted users the ability to add/remove themselves from DLs, which isn't actually uncommon.